# linq query data not showing error

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, gridview

I am trying to show data from DataTable into GridView using a LINQ query but I am not able to understand that why this code is not working.  Actually GridView shows **RowError HasError** message. I am totally confused.

Here's my code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable table = (DataTable)Session["userTable"];
    string compare = Request.QueryString["id"].ToString();
    var data = from x in table.AsEnumerable()
               where x.Field<string>("Userid") == compare
               select x;
    GridView1.DataSource = data;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Can you get any more specific on what the error says?

Comment: Don't you need to do `var dtNew = data .CopyToDataTable(); GridView1.DataSource = dtNew ;
    GridView1.DataBind();` ??

Comment: actually there is no compile or runtime error but it showing nothing in gridview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query returns  `IEnumerable<DataRow>` to convert it to `Datatble` use `CopyToDataTable()` extension. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386921%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable table = (DataTable)Session["userTable"];
    string compare = Request.QueryString["id"].ToString();
    IEnumerable<DataRow> data = from x in table.AsEnumerable()
                                where x.Field<string>("Userid") == compare
                                select x;

    DataTable boundTable = data.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();
    GridView1.DataSource = boundTable;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
var data = from x in table.AsEnumerable()
                    where x.Field<string>("UserId").ToUpper().ToString().Equals(compare.ToUpper().ToString())
                    select x;

        DataTable boundTable = data.AsDataView().ToTable();
        return boundTable;
```